# Why is it different between two types of bash variable usage in maven build

Tags: java, maven

I have a bash script in my maven project to run my application. I compiled my project with two different type of variable usage in my bash script:

1.

```
#!/bin/bash
MAIN_PATH=`dirname $0`
cd $MAIN_PATH
MAIN_PATH=..
MAINCLASS="${component.mainclass}"
LIB_PATH="$MAIN_PATH/lib"
JACOCO_VERSION="${jacoco.version}"
JACOCO_PATH=$LIB_PATH
JACOCO_OPTS=-javaagent:$JACOCO_PATH/jacoco-javaagent-$JACOCO_VERSION.jar=jmx=true,output=tcpserver,address=*,port=6302,includes=*
JAVA_OPTS="${filter.component.java.opts}"
GC_OPTS="${filter.component.gc.opts}"
CLASSPATH=""
CLASSPATH=$MAIN_PATH/config
for f in $MAIN_PATH/lib/*.jar; do
  CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$f
done
echo "java -classpath $CLASSPATH $MAINCLASS"
java $GC_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS -classpath $CLASSPATH $MAINCLASS $*
```

2.

```
MAIN_PATH=`dirname $0`
cd ${MAIN_PATH}
MAIN_PATH=..
MAINCLASS="${component.mainclass}"
LIB_PATH="$MAIN_PATH/lib"
JACOCO_VERSION="${jacoco.version}"
JACOCO_PATH=${LIB_PATH}
JACOCO_OPTS=-javaagent:${JACOCO_PATH}/jacoco-javaagent-${JACOCO_VERSION}.jar=jmx=true,output=tcpserver,address=*,port=6302,includes=*
JAVA_OPTS="${filter.component.java.opts}"
GC_OPTS="${filter.component.gc.opts}"
CLASSPATH=""
CLASSPATH=${MAIN_PATH}/config
for f in ${MAIN_PATH}/lib/*.jar; do
  CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:${f}
done
echo "java -classpath $CLASSPATH $MAINCLASS"
java ${GC_OPTS} ${JAVA_OPTS} -classpath ${CLASSPATH} ${MAINCLASS} $*
```

Filters are as following:

```
filter.component.java.opts=-mx4096M $JAVA_OPTS $JACOCO_OPTS
filter.component.gc.opts=-XX:+UseG1GC
```

`jacoco.version` and `component.mainclass` are defined in the `pom.xml`:

```
<jacoco.version>0.7.6.201602180812</jacoco.version>
<component.mainclass>MyAppStarter</component.mainclass>
```

I build the maven project with this command:

```
mvn clean install -X
```

If I use the first mentioned way of variable definition, the `${JAVA_OPTS}` passing to `java` will be substituted with `-mx4096M` after build, but in the other way `$JAVA_OPTS` will be changed to `-Xmx3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`.

There is no difference between `$JAVA_OPTS` and `${JAVA_OPTS}` in linux bash scripting; what is the difference between these two for `java` or `maven`?

**EDIT 1:**

For the last variable usage I mentioned, the variable substitution for `JAVA_OPTS` happens during build. I mean for the second way, when the maven build completes, the last line does not contain `JAVA_OPTS` anymore, but with the first method, no change occurs.

For the first way the last line after build is:

```
java $GC_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS -classpath $CLASSPATH $MAINCLASS $*
```

And for the seconds one, I receive this as last line:

```
java ${GC_OPTS}  -Xmx3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -classpath  ${MAINCLASS} $*
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have put these two echo commands in both final scripts after the line `JAVA_OPTS="${filter.component.java.opts}"`:

```
echo "test 1 >> "$JAVA_OPTS
echo "test 2 >> "${JAVA_OPTS}
```

And the result for both is the same:

```
test 1 >> -mx4096M -javaagent:../lib/jacoco-javaagent-0.7.6.201602180812.jar=jmx=true,output=tcpserver,address=*,port=6302,includes=*
test 2 >> -mx4096M -javaagent:../lib/jacoco-javaagent-0.7.6.201602180812.jar=jmx=true,output=tcpserver,address=*,port=6302,includes=*
```

**EDIT 3:**

I checked my environment variables before build with an `echo` command:

```
echo 'JAVA_OPTS: '${JAVA_OPTS}
```

It turns out that `JAVA_OPTS` is set in my environments:

```
JAVA_OPTS:  -Xmx3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: plz add `echo $JAVA_OPTS` after line `JAVA_OPTS="${filter.component.java.opts}"` in two scripts and share the results.

Comment: @TaherKhorshidi, please review my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${...}` syntax used by [maven resources plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/index.html):

> These variables, denoted by the ${...} delimiters, can come from the system properties, your project properties, from your filter resources and from the command line.

so at last line of second script, when maven resource plugin see `${JAVA_OPTS}` It searches in environment to find `JAVA_OPTS` and then substitutes it with that.

Comment: Neither `pom.xml` of my project, nor `settings.xml` of maven contains `JAVA_OPTS`. Where does the value of this property come from?

Comment: from envorinment